# ¿Cómo configurar el router para tres controladores diferentes que reciben parámetros?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo 3 controladores diferentes, y están definidos de la siguiente forma:

1. El primero:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public ActionResult About()
       {
           ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
           return View();
       }

       public ActionResult Contact()
       {
           ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```
2. El segundo:

   ```
   public class HellowWorldController : Controller
   {
       // GET: HellowWorld
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }       

       public ActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1)
       {
           ViewBag.message = "Hola " + name;
           ViewBag.NumTimes = numTimes;
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```
3. El tercero:

   ```
   public class JaimeController : Controller
   {
       // GET: Jaime
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }        
       public ActionResult Saludar(string Saludo)
       {
           ViewBag.message = "Hola " + Saludo;
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```

Y en mi archivo de configuración del router lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}                
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Hello",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}"
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      "Saludos",                                          
      "Jaime/{Saludo}",                           
      new { controller = "Jaime", action = "Saludar" }  
    );      
}
```

El problema es que en el controlador que tiene el método `Saludar` no recibe el parámetro, con los demás controladores no hay problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el archivo de rutas, en la ruta `"Saludos"` te falta definir el `name`, la `url` y los `defaults`. De igual forma, si deseas que la `url` de tu controlador quede de forma estática debe ir la acción como `Saludar` y también indicar el nombre del parámetro a recibir:

Debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Saludos",
    url: "Jaime/Saludar/{Saludo}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Jaime", action = "Saludar" }
);
```

---

A pesar de tener una configuración correcta en las rutas, la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) indica que las rutas declaradas de forma específica deben ir al principio del método, dicho de otra forma, la ruta `"Saludos"` debe ser la primer ruta en tu archivo de configuración.

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Saludos",
        url: "Jaime/Saludar/{saludo}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Jaime", action = "Saludar" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}                
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Hello",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}"
    );
}
```

Comment: Ya hice el cambio que me sugeriste pero sigo sin recibir nada, se recibe como null, de esta forma envio el parametro: [http://localhost:55543/Jaime/Saludar/julio]

Comment: Ya hice el cambio pero sigo sin recibir el valor del parámetro, es que estaba trabajando con la plantilla que te genera al crear un proyecto MVC, después agregue  un controlador con sus respectivas vistas y hasta ese momento todo bien, por ultimo agregue otro controlador que con sus respectivas vistas y es ahí donde ya no puedo recuperar el parámetro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que quería, pero  por ejemplo si sigo añadiendo mas controladores, ¿se tienen que ir declarando al inicio?

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev Si son definidos específicamente se deben ir agregando al inicio, es decir, antes del que viene por *default* declarado como `{controller}/{action}/{id}` ;)

Comment: Y por ejemplo si añado otro método al controlador Jaime, que recibe como parámetro un int la configuración del route cambia?

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev no puedes añadir otro controlador `/Jaime` porque ya existe, lo que puedes hacer es ir agregando acciones (métodos) al controlador `/Jaime`. Para esto, entonces debes cambiar tu ruta a  `url: "Jaime/{action}/"` e ir definiendo los parámetros que desees utilizar en cada acción

Comment: [Mejor pásale al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol), allá estoy yo y otros maestros que te pueden ayudar también :D